# Firestore query where(documentId(), 'in', array) is giving me an error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run a query for documents in a collection that match an array of ids (custom document ids), and I'm getting this error:

> Error: The corresponding value for FieldPath.documentId() must be a string or a DocumentReference.

Here is my code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const db = admin.firestore();

let ids = ['12_5', '12_6'];
db.collection('myCollection').where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', ids).get()
```

The documents exist in Firestore, and I created them with custom document ids to be able to easily retrieve the exact documents I need.
[My Documents in Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSZSO.png)

Any ideas on how I can resolve this error?

Comment: it seems `admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()` returns not `string` type or `DocumentReference` type(looks to  documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldPath)

Comment: In which context are you executing this code? In a Cloud Function? In your own node.js environment? Can you give more details on how you declare the Admin SDK?

Comment: Same here, did you ever get past this? I'm doing this in a Firebase Function using the NodeJS Admin SDK, after calling `admin.initializeApp()` of course.

Comment: ... update, I filed an issue here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/990

Comment: How could you fix this issue?

Comment: what is your @google-cloud/firestore version?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the package-lock.json lock file then install the latest @google-cloud/firestore

Answer (score 0):

As of Dec 2022, this now works without issue. `firebase-admin@^11.2.0` defines `where` this way:

```js
where(
  fieldPath: string | FieldPath,
  opStr: WhereFilterOp,
  value: any
): Query<T>;
```

So `where` will no longer require just `DocumentReference` or `string`, but instead accept a `FieldPath`. The OP's code will now work without errors using a recent version of `firebase-admin` or `@google-cloud/firestore`.